# Unresolved external symbol linker error with OpenCV - features 2d

Tags: c++, windows, opencv, windows-8

I'm running the following simple code to define the BRIEF descriptor:

```
#include "cv.h" 
#include "opencv2\objdetect\objdetect.hpp"
#include "opencv2\core\core.hpp"
#include "opencv2\highgui\highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2\calib3d\calib3d.hpp"
#include "opencv2\nonfree\nonfree.hpp"
#include "highgui.h" 
#include "opencv2\features2d\features2d.hpp"
#pragma comment (lib, "opencv_core245d.lib")
#pragma comment (lib, "opencv_highgui245d.lib")
#pragma comment (lib, "opencv_imgproc245d.lib")
#pragma comment (lib, "opencv_video245d.lib")
#pragma comment (lib, "opencv_features2d245d.lib")
using namespace cv;


int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
    BriefDescriptorExtractor Brief(32);


}
```

As you can see, I've added the lib's in pragma and also in the project properties to make sure.

I'm getting the following linker errors:

```
1>OIM2.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual __cdecl cv::Algorithm::~Algorithm(void)" (??1Algorithm@cv@@UEAA@XZ) referenced in function "public: void __cdecl cv::BriefDescriptorExtractor::`vbase destructor'(void)" (??_DBriefDescriptorExtractor@cv@@QEAAXXZ)
1>OIM2.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual __cdecl cv::DescriptorExtractor::~DescriptorExtractor(void)" (??1DescriptorExtractor@cv@@UEAA@XZ) referenced in function "public: virtual __cdecl cv::BriefDescriptorExtractor::~BriefDescriptorExtractor(void)" (??1BriefDescriptorExtractor@cv@@UEAA@XZ)
```

At seems as thought the virtual class of "algorithm" is not recognized and also the BRIEF descriptor class.

Can someone please point as to how to solve this problem? I'm really stomped and I could really use some help.

Thanks,

Gil.

Comment: "I've added the lib's in pragma and also in the project properties to make sure." - that's actually a bad idea (as you loose control of what's used). better stick to the ones in the project properties. ( if you are trying to do a release build later, you'd have to change all the code even! )

Comment: @ChrisMaes, I'm using windows 8. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks @berak, I removed the pragma's. I added all the required libraries in the project properties and it's still not compiling. Do you have any idea how to fix it? thanks!

Comment: tell us the errors you see; are those still the same? How did you install opencv?

Comment: Still the same errors. I've installed OpenCV using Cmake following this tutorial: http://4someonehelp.blogspot.co.il/2013/04/install-opencv-245-using-visual-studio.html#

Comment: @Gil, not really, unfortunately, apart from *triple* checking if you got the right libs there (vs version, 32/64bit, debug/release, the like)

Comment: @berak, I forgot to add, I'm using the libs that I've built after adding a new algorithm to features2d. Could that be the problem?

Comment: ah, already suspected self-build libs when you mentioned cmake. still no real idea. something is off there with the vtables. btw, are you trying to add something to opencv ? (++!) you might consider updating to 2.4.8 then ..

Comment: Hi @berak, I am trying to add something to opencv that me and my supervisor developed. I have new versions of features2d and a cpp that I've added to the OpenCV solution under features2d. Can you please explain what do I need to do in order to use it from outside of the OpenCV solution? I've added more details here:
http://answers.opencv.org/question/30091/trouble-in-running-a-new-algorithm-ive-added-to/

Gil.

Comment: btw, tried removing the build folder and restart with cmake *from scratch* ? and yes, isolating the code first might be another good idea, though you 'll probably run into problems implementing Algorithm::info() ( CV_INIT_ALGORITHM ) maybe [this](http://answers.opencv.org/question/28008/how-to-derive-from-algorithm/) helps

Comment: @berak, once I have a new feature2d.hpp and myAlgorithm.cpp, do I need to build opencv again from scratch using cmake or is it suffice to build it from the OpenCV solution? Thanks!

Comment: at least clean the solution. i'm more and more thinking, you might have used leftover obj files or libs from a previous build

Comment: Thanks @berak, I'll try to clean the solution and rebuild.